# New version is not getting updated autometically

Tags: android, version

We had developed an app few month ago and now we are launching new version of that app, but when we published this app in play-store. It's not getting automatically updated on already installed previous version users. Also for fresh installation if user have old android version they are not getting new version of app, getting old version.

Comment: User's will have to manually update the application from Play Store. It will not get updated automatically.

Comment: In case the user doesn't want to update it, I think there is no way you can force that.

Comment: 'Also for fresh installation if user have old android version they are not getting new version of app, getting old version.' is the new version already live in the store, did you get confirmation that is live?

Comment: If user enable auto-update radio button on the play store, user will update version of your app

Comment: Thanks for reply friends.

It's new version is already live in the store, What you mean by get confirmation that is live?

Comment: Auto-update is already enabled, all above things we have done but still getting same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To be available to users, an update must have the following requirements :

- same `applicationId`
- `versionName` greater than the old one
- same signature

I assume that the OS compatibility has not been changed